# What is the best practice when making a storyboard for iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard, size-classes

I'm making an app that would run on iPad and iPhone but only in landscape mode. The first app that I made was only for iPhone using one storyboard and hAny wAny size classes.

1. What are the good practices when designing an app for iPhone and iPad, regarding usage of storyboards and size classes?
2. Should I make 2 storyboards for each one of them? If so, what would the size classes be?

Comment: use same storyboard for both iphone and ipad that is benefit of size classes.start from hany and wany and add constraints according to your requirement with each size class.

Comment: @johnykumar but if the layout for the ipad is different shouldn't I use 2 storyboards?

Comment: johny kumar is right. 2 separate storyboards practice for developing the Universal apps have been used before the release of size classes in Xcode 6.

Comment: you can arrange layout according to your size class with constraints.e.g if you added any constraint in portrait size class then you can either remove that or add another constraint.if you added any constraint in hany and wany that will be universal if size class for that layout is not available.Note size classes will work only on iOS 8.0 and above not lower than that.

Comment: Johny is wrong about that size classes is only supported for iOS 8. The only you need is Xcode begins from version 6.

Comment: Size classes is a convenient way to layout the given interface for all screen size. Even though you have a different views that can exist for instance for iPhone but be absent for iPad. You simply select a screen dimension (for a need device) and can define whether the certain view would be placed for a specific device or not. And also set a appropriate margins/sizes (aka constrains) for it. You'd think of the Size Classes like :"You have one canvas but you can define the different visual properties for each screen dimension".

Comment: It also compatible with the older versions of iOS versions. This compatibility is realized through building the different Xibs for each screen size underhood. Like you said in your 2nd clause. If you develop under Xcode version bellow 6 U have no choice and have to create several storyboards/Xibs for each device type.

Answer (score 0):

1. You Should use 2 Storyboards. One for iPhone and another for iPod.

Comment: No he shouldn't. Autolayout is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

No need to create two storyboard, you can design an app using auto layout.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Size classes. Start from wAny and hAny. Make appropriate changes for each device switching to different sizes. Using container views will make it more handy.
2. Single storyboard should be sufficient for both iPhone and iPad. A
   storyboard specific to a separate module / User story is preferred.